# HTTP GET request caching vs asp.net Output caching

Tags: caching, browser-cache, http-get, outputcache

I have a very basic doubt about caching. I have sent a request to an aspx page from browser. Since it is an http Get request by default it will be cached. I can see that in about:cache of browser. But if that page is cached, then how my modification (may be in css or js of that particular aspx page) is reflecting on next request. That means it is not taking that from cache?
But At that time cache expire shows something like this "1970-01-01 05:30:00" in about:cache of that aspx request. All other static pages (external js) it is showing future expiry date.
Does a "past expiry" date simply imply that the item should not be "fetched again" from cache?

If enabled Output caching I know the new modification will not see as long as the cache is not expired. But then how this asp.net output cache and http get by default caching mechanism differs? I know Output caching has the facility to cache it in server or proxy, so it will serve for multiple users. But at the browser level how it differs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw I got the answer :)

http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/aspnet-pages-and-browser-caching

Thanks again.